# SML check if a string contains only numbers

Tags: string, int, sml

I want to create a SML function that will return true or false depending on a string that it takes in. It will return true if it only has numbers in it, false otherwise.

ex: 
"4124" - true

"543.234" - false

"f42"   - false

"344g"  - false

I am not that good at using SML, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Is this homework, where the point is to do it from first principles using basic recursion, or is it a practical problem needed for something else (in which case a 1-line solution using things like `List.all` and `Char.isDigit` is the way to go)?

Answer (score 1):

```
fun foo xs = length (List.filter (Char.isDigit) xs) = length xs;

fun boo xs = foo (explode xs);
```

Rename the function as you wish.

```
fun boo xs = List.all (Char.isDigit) (explode xs)
```

also works.

Answer (score 1):

The definition

```
val allDigits = List.all Char.isDigit o explode;
```

(or something similar) is both natural and elegant, but has the drawback that it scans over the data twice, once to create the list of characters and another time to check if all of those characters are digits. SML's eager evaluation means that the entire list is created even if the very first character isn't a digit. This would cause the function to e.g. take over 200,000 steps to verify that the text of Moby Dick isn't all digits.

A solution is to resist exploding the string. Instead, use indices.

It is helpful to first introduce a function which, when passed a function `f` of type `int -> bool` and a pair of ints `a` and `b` returns true if all integers in the interval `[a,b)` satisfy the predicate `f`:

```
fun allInRange f (a,b) = 
    if b <= a then
        true
    else
        f a andalso allInRange f (a+1,b);
```

Since SML short-circuits `andalso`, the recursion terminates as soon as a counterexample to `f` is found in the range (if any -- otherwise it returns `true` of course).

Finally,

```
fun allDigits s = 
    let 
        fun f i = Char.isDigit (String.sub (s,i))
    in
        allInRange f (0, String.size s)
    end;
```

Comment: I think using tail recursion for allInRange will be better.